# how to fix A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname returned ENOSYS in node installing vue cli

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs3, vue-cli

I am using windows 7 as well and installed `npm 9.2.0` and `nodev16.16.0` now when I try to install vue cli and try to check version of the vue cli it is uncounted following error message

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Mara>vue v
node:os:68
      throw new ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR(ctx);
      ^

SystemError [ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR]: A system error occurred: uv_os_gethostname retur
ned ENOSYS (function not implemented)
    at new Defaults (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node
-ipc\entities\Defaults.js:26:20)
    at new Parser (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinza\node-i
pc\entities\EventParser.js:8:14)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinz
a\node-ipc\dao\client.js:11:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\node32\node_modules\@vue\cli\node_modules\@achrinz
a\node-ipc\services\IPC.js:4:14) {
  code: 'ERR_SYSTEM_ERROR',
  info: {
    errno: -4054,
    code: 'ENOSYS',
    message: 'function not implemented',
    syscall: 'uv_os_gethostname'
  },
  errno: [Getter/Setter],
  syscall: [Getter/Setter]
}

C:\Users\Mara>
```

then I found following solution to fix this problem https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1410#issuecomment-1124005921 but unable to how to fix this. anyone could help me

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, the problem can be solved by adding the `hostname-patcher` library (`npm -i hostname-patcher`) before calling the package that causes the error:

```
import 'hostname-patcher'; // import patch first
import os from 'os'; // then os
// or module using os module and causes your error
import { moduleUsingOS } from 'example';

// will output your real hostname if patch and if not
console.log(os.hostname());
```

This bug occurs due to the fact that NodeJS developers, starting with version 14, decided to remove the `GetHostNameW` function (by updated from libuv v1.40 to v1.41), and, in their opinion, for the sake of removing one single function, it is permissible to drop support for Windows 7... Well...

More details about the bug: https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1410 
Developer Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/3878#issuecomment-1748877805

Hostname-patcher github: https://github.com/Bellisario/hostname-patcher

This problem can occur in internal packages, for example when executing the `npm login` command. I don't know yet if there is a way to get around this...

If you have the opportunity (and the desire, which is more difficult) to upgrade to a new Windows, it is better to use this option.